# How to assign all kinds of DbSets to one variable

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to create a variable to which can be assigned all kinds of DbSets and then have possibility to make all CRUD operations on that variable, for example Remove() method? I have tried DbSet with object type but then I have got a compilation error.

My code:

```
DbSet<object> table = null; 

switch (type)
{
    case "Room": table = context.Rooms; break;
    case "Subject": table = context.Subjects; break;
    // table = context.Rooms/Subjects - error
}
```

Comment: You can make a base type with matching abstract methods. I can't think of any other type secure possibility right now.

Comment: A base type won't work because EF needs to know the mapped type to perform the operation on the appropriate set

Answer (score 0):

Well, Entity Framework already has a `DbSet<object>` which is the non-generic `DbSet`. All you have to do is cast it since DbSet has an implicit operator.

```
DbSet table = null;

switch (type) {
   case "Room": table = (DbSet)context.Rooms; break;
   case "Subject": table = (DbSet)context.Subjects; break;
}
```

After you have your DbSet you can get the generic version if you wish.

```
var rooms = table.Cast<Room>()
```

**UPDATE: (for EFCore)** Have you consider to just rely on `DbContext` for this purpose? Your `DbContext` inheriting class in EF Core already has generic and non-generic
methods matching `DbSet<T>` methods for the same things you are trying to achieve.

Here is the list of methods it supports:

- **Add(Object)**
- **Add<TEntity>(TEntity)**
- **AddRange(IEnumerable<Object>)**
- **AddRange(Object[])**
- **Find(Type, Object[])**
- **Find<TEntity>(Object[])**
- **Remove(Object)**
- **Remove<TEntity>(TEntity)**
- **etc...**

Why reinvent the framework

Comment: But it is not possible in Entity Framework Core which I use, here non-generic version of DbSet does not exist. It seems that this feature is not implemented yet.